# Is it possible to access external usb camera using deprecated api android.hardware.Camera

Tags: android

Is it possible to access external usb camera using deprecated api android.hardware.Camera? Also is it possible in new Camera2 api? Then how to use since I'm new to camera functionality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Camera and Camera2 APIs are for interfacing with the built in hardware camera *only*. Depending on what USB camera you are trying to control, there may already be a library/SDK for you to use but Camera and Camera2 will not work for your use case.

Answer (score 1):

To add to Eric Bachhuber's comment:

On a few Android devices, there's support for external USB cameras through the standard camera APIs, but this is not a standard feature.